# Why does next-auth call session multiple times

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Data in session contains access and refresh tokens which in my opinion shouldn't be exposed this often:

[Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y57oD.png)

here's how the session response data looks like:

[Session response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRGXB.png)

What I expect to know is why is this happening, what am I doing wrong and how can I do it better.

Here's my next-auth setup

```js
// path src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "./auth-options";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

```js
import { PATH } from "@/services";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const res = await fetch(PATH.POST_PERFORM_LOGIN, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email: credentials?.email,
              password: credentials?.password,
            }),
          });

          const user = await res.json();
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(" ~ user:", user);

          if (res.ok && user) {
            return user;
          }

          throw new Error(user?.message ?? "Unable to login");
        } catch (error) {
          const e = error as { message: string };

          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(" ~ error:", e);
          throw new Error(e?.message ?? "Unable to login");
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return {
        ...token,
        ...user,
      };
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      return {
        ...session,
        ...token,
        user: token,
      };
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    signOut: "/",
    error: "/login",
  },
};
```

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Yeah i don't understand this too. I only have used 
const session = (await getServerSession(authOptions)) as UserSessionObj; for getting the session object at server component. Still in client it calls auth/session api almost 3-4 times in one page reload.